# Is the vector copied twice in this sample?

Tags: c++, c++11

The Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++ book contains the following code snippet on page 63 in Figure 1.26 for a matrix class (some parts are omitted or truncated):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename Object>
class matrix
{
  public:
    matrix(int rows, int cols);

    matrix(vector<vector<Object>> v) : array{v} { }        
    matrix(vector<vector<Object>>&& v) : array{std::move(v)} { }

    const vector<Object>& operator[](int row) const;
    vector<Object>& operator[](int row);
  private:
    vector<vector<Object>> array;
};
```

In the `matrix(vector<vector<Object>> v)` constructor is `v` being copied twice? Should the signature be `matrix(const vector<vector<Object>>& v)` instead?

There is no mention of this issue in the errata: https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaa_c++4/errata.html

Book citation:

Weiss, M.A.: Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++, International Edition, 2014, Pearson Education Limited.

Comment: "Should the signature be matrix(const vector<vector<Object>>& v) instead?" - that depends on how you *use* `v` inside rhe function.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The use is clearly visible in the question.

Comment: I've submitted this to the errata.

Comment: Heap allocated matrix, the horror

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the first constructor should most certainly take `v` as `const &`; otherwise, you'll get ambiguous overload resolution when constructing from an rvalue (both a value and an rvalue reference are equally good matches then).

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00b0620c8c2f70a7)

But to also answer your question about copying twice: if the rvalue-reference constructor was not present, then passing an lvalue into the first one would indeed result in two copies (once into `v`, and once into `array`). Passing an rvalue could elide the first copy.

In fact, the class would be just fine with just one such constructor:

```
matrix(vector<vector<Object>> v) : array{std::move(v)} { }
```

This results in copy + move when initialising with an lvalue, and (elidable) move + move when initialising with a rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there'll be two copies. It's trivial to mock-up an example to show this happens:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Noisy {
    Noisy() = default;
    Noisy(const Noisy&) { std::cout << "Copy\n"; }
    Noisy(Noisy&&) { std::cout << "Move\n"; }
};

class matrix {
public:
    matrix(Noisy v) : array{v} { }
private:
    Noisy array;
};

int main() {
    Noisy n;
    matrix m{n};
}
```

This should output "Copy" twice.